# Guaranteed CPU cache update after a certain time

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu, cpu-cache

Let's say I have a variable `var` located somewhere in memory and that an arbitrary number of processors/threads could read and modify it at any given time. But it's guaranteed that at least `n` seconds will have elapsed between a processor modifying `var` and any other one reading `var`. Is it possible to be certain that, if time in seconds is `n`, there's a value for `n` that guarantees that the processor reading `var` will read the updated value?

Comment: This question is so generic that I can't imagine how it could possibly be answered usefully. You don't even specify a language, so we have no idea what rules apply or what exactly it means to "read".

Comment: Waaaaay to broad. What type of memory? Which threading model? What language? VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern *really* is [Cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) you should **generally** be safe <sup>1</sup>.
Specifically, however, you may be not.

Cache coherence is usually handled by the hardware<sup>2</sup> without the help of the software.
However this is very implementation specific: [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) may be non cache-coherent, a [Compute Shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_memory_coherency) may need specific built-in functions, IA32e and ARM generally hide cache coherence from the programmer.

To answer you question directly: **No, you have no guarantees whatsoever**.

The point is that *cache coherence* is something you deal with in clustered and parallel non uniform architectures.
While in this situations the programming model is inherently *multi-threading*, the two concepts<sup>3</sup> are separated and what really should bug you is how to properly handle multi-threading, specifically [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) and [memory order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

Your question seems to suggest a simple case, where the readers are executed long after the writer is done.
If this property is **really** enforced you don't need any synchronization nor memory barrier. Beware however that `sleep` functions don't qualify as a valid enforcement.

If you instead need to synchronize (and so to order the memory accesses) then you need to use language specific constructs, for example `volatile` in *C#* and *Java*, `atomics` in *C* and *C++* or specific instructions in *assembly*.
You may need to implement *Critical sections* too.

If you actually need to manually control the cache coherence for your architecture, than you have to check the specifications of interest (usually datasheets and formal papers) because there is no uniform way to deal with it and the compiler should provide some intrinsic or the runtime should provide a library.

So to add something to the direct answer above: **No, you have no guarantees whatsoever, but when an *usual* CPU, in an *usual* architecture, need that data, it will be able to use the most updated one anyway. So you don't need to worry about *that* aspect.**

<sub><sup>Please note the use of the words *common* and *that*</sup></sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> For example if you use an *Intel*/*AMD*/*ARM* CPU, don't even think about cache coherence.
<sup>2</sup> Either the CPU itself, a local monitor, a system monitor or a specific device.
<sup>3</sup> Multi-threading and cache-coherence.

Comment: I have already made the same comment 2 days ago - `If this property is really enforced you don't need any synchronization nor memory barrier. ` is not correct. There are ways to uncoditionally enforce the ordering which are outside of threading model, and as such, still require proper threading model - supported ordering/synchronization.

Comment: @SergeyA mmm.. Could you clarify? Enforcing that thread B run after thread A is itself a form of synchronization, so my statement "*don't need any sync*" is little white lie (meant to be, don't need any programmer aware synchronization). That's why I used the word "**really**".

Comment: Well, there are different synchronizations around here. Let's stay within Posix threading model for clarity. Posix defines it's own synchronizarion protocols (we all know them) which by definition impose memory ordering. But there are other ways to synchronize your threads outside of Posix model - for example, you can use `eventfd` on Linux for this. And while those will provide synchronization as in ordering of execution, they are not guaranteed to provide memory ordering (while they are more than likely to do so simply by their nature).

Answer (score 0):

The cache will tend to get flushed on operating system tick interrupts when it goes into the scheduler to see if there's a different task to run.

However, as operating systems get smarter with things such as tickless NoHz and as CPU core counts go up, this gets less and less likely, and you shouldn't count on it.

Supercomputer clusters may not task switch for minutes at a time because they're using customized operating system code that doesn't interrupt the running jobs, ever. Compute jobs are assigned to a core from 1-7 with no interrupts and all of the other work runs on core-0.

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts mixed in you question: software synchronization and hardware coherency. Hardware coherency is talked by Margaret already so I won't cover it here.

**Software Synchronization**

x86 provides guarantee that quadword access would be carried out atomically if aligned on 64-bit boundary. But this guarantees that other processor won't read partial result (e.g. [32bit New]<32bit Old> weird mixture). It does not guarantee a hard time deadline before which another processor would see the newly assigned value. Let another thread wait for some time is not quite an elegant solution because first the two threads need to have the same starting time synchronized. So, if you need such guarantee, you need conditional variable to make sure another thread should wait.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)

In a word, use conditional variable if you need a sequencing effect and use locks/transactional memory, etc. to protect variable longer than quadword or not 64bit aligned.

Btw, here is an useful material for cache coherency if you are interested.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15418-s12/www/lectures/10_coherence.pdf